# Is it possible to sort queryset without hitting the db again?

Tags: python, django, database

Is there any approach to avoid hitting db when the queryset needs to be
returned in a specific order?

If a queryset would be returned when a page is loaded

```
qs = Student.objects.all()[start:end]
```

But it also provides UI for users to view the query in ascending or descending
order.
So, at Django server.

Queries should be performed

```
qs = Student.objects.all()[start:end]
qs2 = Student.objects.filter(id__in=qs).order_by("-id")
```

To reduce the db hitting, is there any other better approach to
avoid frequent query and db hit?

I wonder I would store the query result in browser and return the results
but it looks so complex...

Comment: i thing so can use template tags for that.

Comment: After calling [start:end] it return list,and then you can do what you want. Sorting, filtering as python list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's built in function `sorted()`. You have to pass iterable object and key function to `sorted()` function.

In your case, you can try:

```
qs = Student.objects.all()[start:end]
sorted_qs = sorted(qs, key=lambda obj: obj.id)
```

Comment: It's pretty smart! But can I avoid to query http query as the user wants to see an ordered list?